# How to mock values in multiple layer of calls in springboot mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, powermockito

I have a service in Spring Boot and I have a function call logic defined as follows:

```
public class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA {

    public ObjectA createObjectA(InputA inputA) {
        ObjectA objectA = ObjectCreateHelper.createObject(createObjectB(), inputA);

        return objectA;
    }

    private ObjectB createObjectB() {
        ObjectB objectB = ObjectB.newBuilder().setSpecialID(Tracker.getSpecialID()).build();
        return objectB;

    }

}
```

And my Test is this:

```
public class ServiceAImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceAImpl mockServiceAImpl;

    private MockedStatic<ObjectCreatorHelper> mockObjectCreateHelper;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        mockObjectCreateHelper = mockStatic(ObjectCreateHelper.class);
        mockServiceAImpl = new ServiceAImpl();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void close() {
        mockObjectCreateHelper.close();
    }


    @Test
    public void givenWhenThen() {
        //given 
        InputA mockInputA = mockInputA();
        ObjectA mockObjectA = mockObjectA();
        mockObjectCreateHelper.when(() -> createObject(any(ObjectB.class), any(InputA.class)).thenReturn(mockObjectA);
        //when
        ObjectA objectA = serviceAImpl.createObjectA(mockInputA);

        //then
        assertEquals(mockObjectA, objectA);
       
    }


}
```

I was having a problem making it passed because Tracker.getSpeicalID() needs a real context or otherwise it will be null and then NPE will be thrown. I would like to know how to mock my test correctly so that I can pass in a real/mock value of this special ID instead of null?

Comment: You change your design to not access global state, but pass in dependencies explicitly. Then you can simply swap them with dummy implementations in your tests

Answer (score 1):

There are few options.

- (preferred). You need to leverage a dependency injection technique (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Let your ServiceAImpl accept some `TrackerIdProvider` instead of calling static `Tracker.getSpecialId()`.
- Another option (much worse one, since it will keep your technical debt) is to use another mocking library, which allows you to mock static methods such as PowerMock: https://powermock.github.io/ (See https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)

I would strongly recommend you to use the first option and redesign your service to accept external dependencies via constructor or in some other way.